# Trying to pull the total Count from 2 different database with some of the same columns

Tags: sql

I cant seem to figure our how to join these 2 database together to get  my totals. `DBO.Agent` has columns `agentid`, `buisnesslineID` and `TeamID`. `DBO.Buinessline` has Columns `ParentbusinsesslineID` and `BusinessLineID`.

```
SELECT  A.Agentid,A.BusinessLineID,A.TeamID,B.ParentBusinessLineID, Count (*) AS Total
FROM Dbo.BusinessLine AS B LEFT JOIN Dbo.Agent AS A ON A
WHERE
```

Comment: The obvious would be to join them on the `businesslineID`.

Comment: As WWI_DBA states it could be likley that businessLineId is relational between the 2 tables.  You mention "to get my totals" but you never say what you are trying to count.  All records? Records per line of Business?  It would be good to tag the db platform you are using, sql-server, orcale, mysql etc. And present some example data and desired result.

Comment: all records is what im trying to get the count for.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the total count from both tables:

```
DECLARE @BusinessLineCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dbo.BusinessLine )

DECLARE @AgentCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dbo.Agent)

SELECT @BusinessLineCount + @AgentCount
```